# Expression to the right of set builder notation

Tags: algorithms, notation

I'm trying to make sense of some mathematical notation I'm seeing in a common clustering algorithm I've been reading about.  The algorithm is laid out [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/img1572.png) (as an image).  I'm a bit confused about line 10, specifically, which reads:

$$k_1 \leftarrow \operatorname{argmax}_{\{k\,:\,I[k]=1\}} P[k].\mathrm{Max}().\mathrm{sim}$$

I'm having difficulty making sense of the notation.  What I understand here is that we're assigning a value to $k_1$.  Then we have an $\operatorname{argmax}$ function, and the set builder notation (in subscript) $\{k:I[k]=1\}$, meaning a set containing all $k$ where $I[k]=1$.  But I don't understand how the set builder notation relates to the expression which follows it, where we take the max value in $P[k]$.  How is the argmax and set-builder notation related to the $P[k].\operatorname{Max}()$ expression?  There's no operator (is it multiplication?) so I don't know how to read what's going on here.

Comment: What is the `_.sim` member at the end?

Comment: It is a similarity value - (a distance between two points) - basically the maximum value in $P[k]$

Comment: Do you know what argmax means without set builder notation?  The meaning isn't different here.

Answer (score 1):

The line says "assign to $k_1$ a $k$ that satisfies both: $I[k]=1$ and maximizes $P[k].\max.\operatorname{sim}$".

(Without some parenthesis it is hard to say wether $.\operatorname{sim}$ is being applied to the argmax result or to the result of $\max$)